# Как работать с donationalerts на python?

Tags: python-3.x

Я знаю что у Donationalerts есть API, но я не понял как это использовать в коде.

Comment: https://www.donationalerts.com/apidoc#api_v1

Comment: Посмотри их [документацию](https://www.donationalerts.com/apidoc). Тут тебе и как отправить запрос, и еще куча всего. Я в этом не разбираюсь, поэтому ничего особо сказать не смогу